# How do I pass a personalization string variable through Ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This is my code that sets the variables and pulls them from an rss feed (which is set in a content area).

```
%%[Var @xml, @xml1, @title<br>
        Set @xml1 = ContentAreaByName(&quot;my contents\StartingaBusiness&quot;)<br>
        Set @xml = Replace(@xml1,'content:encoded','contentencoded')<br>
        Set @xml = Replace(@xml,'media:content','mediacontent')<br>
        Set @title = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,&quot;//item/title&quot;,1)
```

How do I pass a personalization string like `%%emailname_%%` through the ContentAreaByName, like:

```
Set @xml1 = ContentAreaByName(&quot;my contents\%%emailname_%%&quot;)
```

Their documentation says to not use the %% , but that doesn't work in this case.

Or is there a way I can pass the @title variable in it? Like:

```
Set @xml1 = ContentAreaByName(&quot;my contents\@title&quot;)<br>
```

Comment: Do you really intend to use the `&quot;` in your code samples?

Answer (score 1):

The way I typically would do this is with the `Concat()` function. Currently, the `ContentAreaByName()` function is treating the entire parameter as a string, and not replacing the personalization string first.

Try this

```
Set @xml1 = ContentAreaByName(Concat("my contents\",emailname_))
```